# Удаление части с куки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, имею куку такого вида 58;42;43;60;15. как из этой строки удалить цифру например 43; средствами php,ну и обратно в куку сам занесу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$old = explode(";","58;42;43;60;15");
$new = array();
foreach ($old as $v) {
    if ($v != "43") {
        $new[] = $v;
    }
}
$new = implode(";", $new);
```

Можно через `preg_grep`:

```
$old = "58;42;43;60;15";
$new = implode(";",preg_grep("/^43$/", explode(";",$old),PREG_GREP_INVERT));
```